# CSS3 Technique for White-Outlined, Red Text

Tags: css, fonts

I'm not associated in any form with the following page:

http://www.wpsyndicator.com/

However, as you can see on that page, they used images to show the white-outlined, shadowed, red text. Is there a way in CSS3 to implement this feature? I mean, I can handle the shadow and the red, but the white font outlining is not something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for text-stroke.

`-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white`;

It is only supported by the web-kit for now, you can see the compatibility list here http://caniuse.com/text-stroke

More Info:

http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

http://www.webkit.org/blog/85/introducing-text-stroke/

Here is an example from David: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h5J6K/2/

Comment: Somehow I posted my answer after yours, without having realised that you'd already answered. Weird. May I offer a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h5J6K/2/)?

Comment: BTW, for Internet Exploder, one can mix -ms-filter with a drop shadow filter: http://jsfiddle.net/kovalchik/yJff9/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css3 text-shadow property to achieve this effect. Will not work in IE tho so will have to find some one to emulate the effect in that browser. The code looks like this...
    #myDiv {
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff, 2px 2px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 1px #fff, -2px -2px 1px   #fff;
    }

The first argument is the horizontal distance from the text, the second, the vertical, the third is the blur. the lower this number the less blur. you do negatives to go up or to the left. This is cool and you can do some really neat effects with this. Hope that helps

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis-I thought the text stroke wasn't as widely supported. Has this changed?